# Gdbscript doesn't continue when using python fin

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, gdbserver

I debug a Linux process using GDB. I want that GDB will break on `SomeFunction` wait until the function will finish `gdb.execute('fin')` and then print `finish` and continue

```
b SomeFunction
commands
silent 
python

i = gdb.inferiors()[0]
gdb.execute('fin')
print('finish')
end
c
end
```

The problem is that even GDB print `finish` it doesn't continue automatically (with `c` )

Why is that?

Comment: The [docu](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html) says: `Any other commands in the command list, after a command that resumes execution, are ignored.` And `finish` is a command that resumes execution.

Comment: @ssbssa Is there any solution for that ? I must that GDB script will run automatically

Comment: Maybe with a [python `FinishBreakpoint`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Finish-Breakpoints-in-Python.html).